# Создание в объекте нового объекта с массивом одной командой

Tags: javascript

Есть обычный объект:

```
let obj= {
   0: array('a', 'v', 3);
};
```

В какой-то момент времени я дополняю его

```
obj[0].push('new');
```

Но если мне нужно добавить данные в строку объекта, которой еще не было, то я получу ошибку. Так не работает:

```
obj[7].push('new_str');
```

Как сделать подобное? Нужно вводить проверку на существование индекса объекта, и если такого нет, то создавать его сначала? Или можно короче?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте объекту метод:

```
let obj = { ... }; 

obj.pushTo = function (index, value) {
  if (!this[index]) 
    this[index] = []; 
  this[index].push(value); 
};
```

, и используйте его одной строкой:

```
obj.pushTo(7, 'new_str');
```

---

*Проверка на тип в методе не нужна, потому что если программист сам засунет в объект не-массив, и попытается работать с ним как с массивом - это будет ошибка программиста (и в таких ситуациях **должно** выбрасываться исключение).*

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению нужно проверить существует ли массив и массив ли это((

```js
let obj = {
   0: ['a', 'v', 3]
};
obj[0].push('new');
if (Array.isArray(obj[7])) {
  obj[7].push('new');
  console.log("1", obj);
}
obj[7] = [];
if (Array.isArray(obj[7])) {
  obj[7].push('new');
  console.log("2", obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно как-то так:

```
obj[7] ? obj[7].push('new_str') : obj[7] = [],obj[7].push('new_str');
```

Answer (score 1):

Именно одной командой вот так:

```js
var obj=
{
   0: ['a', 'v', 3]
};
//Одновременное создание массива и добавление первой записи:
if(!obj[7])
 obj[7] = ['new_str'];
else obj[7].push('new_str');

console.log(obj[7]);
```

Это можно сделать и без проверки `if(!obj[7])`, но тогда будет перезапись массива, если таковой уже есть.